# Displaying tables

Tags: feature-request

The SO documentation site uses some fancy tables to display tabular data ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join#t=201608010929062075554)).

DBA.se is badly in need of a nice way of displaying tabular data, and the tables on the documentation site look brilliant.

Is there a chance that they can be ported to DBA.se?

Comment: As Adam mentioned in [his answer on the dup](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/966/9003) the table display is available in CommonMark which is a part of docs. The eventual plan is to switch Q&A to that, but we're taking 6-8 somethings.

Comment: I was hoping this feature would be implemented about 12 megasomethings ago, but I'll settle for maybe 150 microsomethings from now.